# How to render the data to another template after submitting the Django-Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to do the following things:

User will open a page i.e. `network_form.html` and fill the form which contain two fields (see the form.py)

After submitting that form. Server will perform calculation on the bases of these two fields and render the calculated data to another page i.e. `subnet_network.html`

Take a look on from.py:

```
 class SubnetCreateFrom(forms.Form):
     Subnet_Address = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
     IP_Address = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Now i want to submit these form fields and want to process some query on the bases of these field. So, i write the following vies.py:

```
 def subnet_network(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = SubnetCreateFrom(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         subnet = form.data['Subnet_Address']
         ip = form.data['IP_Address']
         # Here i am manipulating the data using the above subnet and ip fields and pass the data in the form of parameter to the follwing method. i.e. get_host_list
         subnet_network_detail(request,get_hosts_list) #[1]
         return HttpResponseRedirect('../../list/')
 extra_context = {
     'form': SubnetCreateFrom(initial={'user': request.user.pk})
 }
 return direct_to_template(request, 'networks/network_form.html',
                          extra_context)
```

Template network_form.html:

```
  <form action="" method="POST">
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Show Host" %}"/>
  </form>
```

when the form has been filled by a user after clicking on the submit button. Ot should open a new page showing the processing data i.e. `get_host_list`. That is why i called a subnet_network_detail method from the mid of the above defined subnet_network method So that we can render that data to the next template. is this right way to do it ?

Definition of  subnet_network_detail are following: (which also in the same views.py)

```
 def subnet_network_detail(request,list_hosts):
    extra_context = {
       'subnet_hosts': list_hosts
       }#[2]
    return direct_to_template(request, 'networks/subnet_network.html',
                           extra_context)
```

Url pattern for above methods are following:

```
url(r'^myapp/netmask/create/$',
    'subnet_network', name='subnet_network'),
url(r'^myapp/netmask/select/$',
    'subnet_network_detail', name='subnet_network_detail')
```

Is there something wrong with URL pattern. 
Why i am not able to rendering the data accessing from `SubnetCreateForm` to another template i.e. `subnet_network.html`. Is this the right way to call that method or render the data to a template?

Following things are happening when i check with the pdb putting it different different places:

```
[1] I used the python debugger at this position and it shows an error i.e. subnet_network_detail receiving one parameter and you are passing it two

[2] After removing the pdb syntax from [1] and putting at this position i check whether the data is passing to this function or not and it was. I am getting the data what i want in list_hosts variable 



And also after removing the pdb syntax from [2] position it redirect to the page what we have written in HttpResponseRedirect in the first method
```

Comment: As an aside, you should get subnet and ip from the form's [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data), not `data`.

Comment: define 'not able to submit the form' ? Maybe there's something wrong with your form template, please post its source.

Comment: @Alasdair I did that but it was showing an error that there is no attribute for this

Comment: @jpic Sure i am going to post the ***network/form.html*** but it contains nothing. However the the form part are running successfully but i don't what is happening. Or simple how should i do?

Comment: You did not **define 'not able to submit the form'** in your answers. Don't just say **it doesn't work** as it makes it **almost impossible** to understand what you're doing, what happens, and what you were expecting. If you **don't know what's happening** then you should **use a debugger** like pdb/ipdb/winpdb/etc ...

Comment: @AmitPal that's weird. If the form is valid, it should have a `cleaned_data` attribute. Anyway, that's not the main issue here. Hope you get it working.

Comment: @Alasdair I used pdb to check whether the data is present in subnet and ip variable and it shows the right one.

Comment: @jpic I used a pdb to check whether the data is passing to the  or subnet_network_detail method or not. And it was right. But when i remove the pdb command it shows nothing and the page defined in return HttpResponseRedirect('../../list/') will open after the submitting the form

Comment: "it shows nothing" ... i have no idea what you're talking about. Anyway, it looks like you have an indentation problem in your view code so that might be a problem.

Comment: @jpic check the update one! I have put the [] in the code line where i put the pdb syntax and see what i was getting

Comment: @jpic I have put the **import pdb;pdb.set_trace at [1] [2] position in the code and got that error. When i am submitting the form with all above code why is redirect to HttpResponseRedirect('../../list/'). In meanwhile i am also calling a method and in that method i am rendering the data to another template.

Comment: Hi@Amit Pal，can you put the updated and corrected code? I face similar problem as you, really appreciated if you could post the final code.

Comment: @miaomiao Ah! I am so sorry. Actually I asked this question two years back :(